# How correctly bind data to radio buttons in Angular2?

Tags: angular, data-binding, radio-button

I have a component with two radio buttons, HTML looks like :

```
<div class="btn-group"  id="ProfitCodes">
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio"
           class="radio-inline"
           value="1"
           [checked]="model.ForeignCompany.ProfitCode === 1"
           [(ngModel)]="model.ForeignCompany.ProfitCode"
           id="point1"
           name="ProfitCode"><small>description</small>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio"
           class="radio-inline"
           [(ngModel)]="model.ForeignCompany.ProfitCode"
           [checked]="model.ForeignCompany.ProfitCode === 2"
           value="2"
           id="point2"
           name="ProfitCode"><small>description</small>
    </label>
</div>
```

When I click save and send model to server I see valid selected value of radio button on server side. And this value stored in the database without errors. But radio button with appropriate value is not checked after binding data.
In devTools I see the first radio button:

```
<input class="radio-inline ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="point1" name="ProfitCode" title="asdasda" type="radio" value="1" ng-reflect-name="ProfitCode" ng-reflect-value="1" ng-reflect-model="2" ng-reflect-checked="false">
```

Second radio button:

```
<input class="radio-inline ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="point2" name="ProfitCode" title="asd" type="radio" value="2" ng-reflect-name="ProfitCode" ng-reflect-value="2" ng-reflect-model="2" ng-reflect-checked="true">
```

I see that angular changed attributes and waiting that second radio button will be checked. But this does not happen.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ngModel and checked do not work together , you must remove one of them .

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This works in my case. I removed `[(ngModel)]`

```
<div class="radio">
<label>
    <input type="radio"
           value="1"
           [checked]="model.ForeignCompany.ProfitCode === 1"
           id="point1"
           (change)="onProfitSelectionChange(1)"
           name="ProfitCode"><small>description</small>
</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio"
               value="2"
               [checked]="model.ForeignCompany.ProfitCode === 2"
               id="point2"
               (change)="onProfitSelectionChange(2)"
               name="ProfitCode"><small>description</small>
    </label>
</div>
```

and TS method looks like:

```
onProfitSelectionChange(entry): void {
    this.model.ForeignCompany.ProfitCode = entry;
}
```

Comment: You can also listen for the change event on a wrapper div for all the radio buttons. The value of the change is then accessible as `$event.target.value`. This saves repeating the `(change)` listener for every radio button.

Comment: I tried a bunch of different ways to get the radio button to bind directly to the data source using ngModel (like I do for checkboxes), but none of the ways worked for me, so I had to use an event handler.

Comment: hey can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284568/value-is-not-getting-bind-for-radio-button-in-angular-for-rating-component) question? this is not woking for me, rather i have been searching for answers since last 3 days, my question is there unanswered since 2 days.

Answer (score 35):

You don't need `[checked]`. Try with `[(ngModel)]`. Also, use `[value]="1"` instead of `value="1"`

```html
  <input type="radio" name="Coverage" [value]="1" 
    [(ngModel)]="formdata.coverage_verified"  />Yes
```

Comment: Why would you use binding if value is static?

Comment: In this case, binding the constant value 1 makes the input value to be a number (instead of the string "1")

Answer (score 3):

```
<label *ngFor="let status of statuses">
    <input type="radio" name="name" [(ngModel)]="entity.status" [value]="status.id">
    <b>{{ status.name | i18n }}</b>
</label>
```

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let type of types">
   <label class="m-radio m-radio--bold m-radio--state-success">
      <input name="selectedType" [(ngModel)]="selectedType" [value]="type" type="radio">
           {{type.title}}
      <span></span>
   </label>
</ng-container>
```