# Value is not getting bind for radio button in Angular for rating component

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

i have a project where I want to have the rating component (reusable) which i can use on other component, for that i have written some CSS psudo selectors as well which are not getting applied on page load. i have tried allmost all the answers on this forum but nothing is working

for e.g. [After adding [(ngModel)] to a radio button group, the default [checked] no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443903/after-adding-ngmodel-to-a-radio-button-group-the-default-checked-no-longe)
and many more.

Twist:
Then just to identify(after lot of tries and reading answers) and try out, i added that component in some other project of mine and it is working perfectly there. on page load if the `ts` file has `starrating=3` then 3 stars are getting selected on page load.

after that just to share on this forum i created this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kaf2tp?file=src/rating/rating/rating.component.ts) but that is also *working*.
now i will share code for BAD project and GOOD project as well, not sure what is the issue

**BAD PROJECT**

```
HTML

<!-- star rating -->
<div class="rating-wrapper">

  <!-- star 5 -->
  <input type="radio" id="5-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="5" [checked]="starrating === '5'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="5-star-rating" class="star-rating">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>

  <!-- star 4 -->
  <input type="radio" id="4-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="4" [checked]="starrating === '4'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="4-star-rating" class="star-rating star">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>

  <!-- star 3 -->
  <input type="radio" id="3-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="3" [checked]="starrating === '3'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="3-star-rating" class="star-rating star">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>

  <!-- star 2 -->
  <input type="radio" id="2-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="2" [checked]="starrating === '2'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="2-star-rating" class="star-rating star">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>

  <!-- star 1 -->
  <input type="radio" id="1-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="1" [checked]="starrating === '1'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="1-star-rating" class="star-rating star">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>
 
</div>
```

components TS file
ts file

```
import { Component,  OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'FH-rating',
  templateUrl: './rating.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rating.component.css']
})
export class RatingComponent implements OnInit {

  starrating="3";   /// <==== THESE ARE THE STARS THAT I WANT TO HAVE SELECTED BY DEFAULT ON PAGE LOAD
//coachrating:string='5';
  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit(): void {

  }}
```

CSS file
CSS file

```
.container-wrapper {
  background-color: #EDF0F9;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.rating-wrapper {
  align-self: center;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 25px rgba(198, 206, 237, 0.7), -7px -7px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), inset 0px 0px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), inset 7px 7px 15px rgba(198, 206, 237, 0.8);
  border-radius: 4rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  direction: rtl !important;
  padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.rating-wrapper label {
  color: #E1E6F6;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.6rem;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}
.rating-wrapper svg {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow 4px 1px 6px #c6ceed;
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 1px 3px #c6ceed);
}
.rating-wrapper input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.rating-wrapper input {
  display: none;
}
.rating-wrapper label:hover,
.rating-wrapper label:hover ~ label,
.rating-wrapper input:checked ~ label {
  color: #34AC9E;
}
.rating-wrapper label:hover,
.rating-wrapper label:hover ~ label,
.rating-wrapper input:checked ~ label {
  color: #34AC9E;
}
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "fit-hub",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

now the good project. Trust me when i say the `html,ts,css` file exact copy of them, so i will put just package.json here for GOOD project

**GOOD PROJECT**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "event-hub",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "angularx-social-login": "^4.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

When I inspect my radio button in my edge i see that the GOOD project has code generated something like below

`<input _ngcontent-bqk-c61="" type="radio" id="1-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="1" ng-reflect-name="star-rating" ng-reflect-value="1" ng-reflect-model="3" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">`

but when i see my BAD project elemet i see like below

`<input _ngcontent-yor-c47="" type="radio" id="1-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="1" ng-reflect-name="star-rating" ng-reflect-value="1">`

please observe the `ng-reflect-model` has been added by angular, what is that I am missing? need help badly

**EDIT 1**

putting code for GOOD project as well, it might help,

html

```
<!-- star rating -->
<div class="rating-wrapper">

  <!-- star 5 -->
  <input type="radio" id="5-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="5" [checked]="starrating === '5'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="5-star-rating" class="star-rating">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>

  <!-- star 4 -->
  <input type="radio" id="4-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="4" [checked]="starrating === '4'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="4-star-rating" class="star-rating star">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>

  <!-- star 3 -->
  <input type="radio" id="3-star-rating" name="star-rating" value="3" [checked]="starrating === '3'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="3-star-rating" class="star-rating star">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>

  <!-- star 2 -->
  <input type="radio" id="2-star-rating" name="star-rating"  value="2" [checked]="starrating === '2'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="2-star-rating" class="star-rating star">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>

  <!-- star 1 -->
  <input type="radio" id="1-star-rating" name="star-rating"  value="1" [checked]="starrating === '1'" [(ngModel)]="starrating">
  <label for="1-star-rating" class="star-rating star">
    <i class="fa fa-star d-inline-block"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-star',
  templateUrl: './star.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./star.component.css']
})
export class StarComponent implements OnChanges {

  // @Input() rating: number;
  // starWidth: number;
  // @Output() notifyRatingChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
   starrating="4";
//coachrating:string='5';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    //this.starWidth = this.rating * 75 / 5;
  }

  onClick(): void {
   // this.notifyRatingChange.emit("clicked!");
    //console.log(`${this.rating} was clicked`);
  }

}
```

Comment: @msanford i see you were facing something similar can you help?

Comment: @mickdev any help would be appreciated